# PayPal PHP SDK REST API Response not JSON

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I get an object with nested arrays of nested objects when I make an API call.  In the SDK I have the header set to accept: application/json.  I am wondering why I am getting objects and arrays back?

Here is a partial part of the response:

```
PayPal\Api\CreditCard Object
(
    [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
        (
            [type] => amex
            [number] => xxxxxxxxxxx0005
            [expire_month] => 5
            [expire_year] => 2015
            [cvv2] => 1234
            [first_name] => 
            [last_name] => 
            [payer_id] => 3zIVtTFQ7UdKjP5mssjtzoUo6NvrsExl466oPC4Mm8nwOjI6BS
            [id] => CARD-35X96613EN689504VKKCA4RA
            [state] => ok
            [valid_until] => 2015-06-01T00:00:00Z
            [create_time] => 2013-11-13T23:41:56Z
            [update_time] => 2013-11-13T23:41:56Z
            [links] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
                        (
                            [_propMap:PayPal\Common\PPModel:private] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/CARD-35X96613EN689504VKKCA4RA
                                    [rel] => self
                                    [method] => GET
                                )

   )

[1] => PayPal\Api\Links Object
```

... and so on
Code that creates this

```
public static function get($creditCardId, $apiContext = null) { 
    if (($creditCardId == null) || (strlen($creditCardId) <= 0)) { 
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("creditCardId cannot be null or empty"); 
    }
    $payLoad = ""; 
    if ($apiContext == null) { 
         $apiContext = new ApiContext(self::$credential); 
    } 
    $call = new PPRestCall($apiContext); 
    print_r($call); 
    die;
    $json = $call->execute(array('PayPal\Rest\RestHandler'), "/v1/vault/credit-card/$creditCardId", "GET", $payLoad); 
    $ret = new CreditCard(); 
    $ret->fromJson($json); 
    return $ret;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so thank you Machavity for the help.  The issue was that in the function that I posted above, it takes the JSON response and converts it to some wierd object thing with:

```
$ret->fromJson($json);
```

I removed that line and I now get JSON.  I still wonder why having that object I intitially posted would be helpful and where it could be used.  I also wonder why the SDK documentation doesn't explicitly state that the SDK does *not* return JSON as the final format.  I feel it would save a lot of time if PayPal informed a developer that the response gets converted to an object, so we wouldn't have to search through thousands of lines of code to figure it out.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to simply get the raw JSON that is 'sent' and then 'received' through the PHP PayPal SDK... for logging/tracking purposes! I don't want the entire object wrapper and handler of the SDK, I just want the payloads going to and from paypal for logging (because the SDK logger is broken/does not work at all).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the SDK is accepting JSON on the communications layer and then running [json_decode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to pass you back an object you can work with. My own API system converts the response back into a PHP array.

Comment: Hmm, the interesting thing is when I search through the documentation, it only list JSON as a response.  I feel like I am missing something.

Comment: The raw response (what PayPal is sending you) is likely in JSON. You'll have to build your own request or modify the SDK to see it tho.

Comment: I am still at a loss.  I have the configuration set to return JSON.  What I posted is a print_r() of the response, so the SDK hasn't manipulated the response yet.  

I guess, if this is "normal", how do I access all of the data inside this object.  The array keys in the objects have slashes and semi-colons and that isn't something I have dealt with before.  In other API's I have worked with, it is just a simple json response?

Comment: The SDK has parsed the response for you and you apparently reference it through the object. Can you post your code so I can see your calls?

Comment: The function that makes the call:

public static function get($creditCardId, $apiContext = null) {
  if (($creditCardId == null) || (strlen($creditCardId) <= 0)) {
   throw new \InvalidArgumentException("creditCardId cannot be null or empty");
  }
  $payLoad = "";
  if ($apiContext == null) {
   $apiContext = new ApiContext(self::$credential);
  }
  $call = new PPRestCall($apiContext);
  print_r($call); die;
  $json = $call->execute(array('PayPal\Rest\RestHandler'), "/v1/vault/credit-card/$creditCardId", "GET", $payLoad);
  $ret = new CreditCard();
  $ret->fromJson($json);
  return $ret;

Answer (score 0):

json_decode( $call->execute(array('PayPal\Rest\RestHandler'), "/v1/vault/credit-card/$creditCardId", "GET", $payLoad) );